# z3 with workflow satisfiability

Tags: z3

I am new using Z3, and after a lot of tutorial an reading almost all the related questions I still have some doubts about how to "encode" a problem with Z3. CAN SOMEBODY HELP ME PLEASE?.. 
What I am trying to do is to encode the satisfiability problem with Z3.
I have two arrays representing roles (a role-task relation), and privileges (a user-role relation) . I also have a datatype which is a User-Role pair representing the "attributes" of a task.

```
(declare-datatypes (User Role) ((Pair (mk-pair (first User) (second Role)))))
(declare-const Privs (Array User Role))
(declare-const Roles (Array Role (Pair User Role)))
```

then I am trying to assert that for any task (for all) there is an element in Privs which contains a user-role relation and in Roles and element which contains a Role-"Task"(user-role pair) like this.

```
(assert (forall ((l (Pair User Role)))
        (and (= (select Privs (first oneTask)) (second oneTask))  
        (= (select Roles (second oneTask)) oneTask))))
```

Until there I am getting a Sat answer and a model (uninterpreted since I am using uninterpreted sorts).

But here is where my doubts begins....

1) The next step is ask if when having two workflows with a list of tasks (user-role pair) I can assert the same for all the tasks in the list. I tried creating a new const which is a list of tasks like this:

```
(declare-const Workflow (List (Pair User Role)))
```

is there any way in Z3 to specify an assert over ALL the elements of a list (workflow in my case) ??

2) How can one specify restrictions like over the set of users or assignments , and moreover how can one express limits in the time of executions for instance.. an execution of a set of taks couldnt take more than n seconds??..

3) Is there any way to get an interpreted model when using interpreted taks, lets say something like ... when PRIVS = (U1, R1) , (U2,R2)  and Role= (R1,T1)  and wf =T1(U1,R1)

Can somebody help me please to get how to attack the problem from a Z3 view?????PLEASE!!

Comment: I JUST NEED AN IDEA OF HOW TO MAP THE PROBLEM AND EXPRESS IT..MAYBE AND EXAMPLE OF SOMETHING SIMILAR WILL HELP ME A LOT.!

Answer (score 1):

1. Z3 supports standard first-order quantification. If you want to quantify over a what amounts to the elements of a container object (List), you will be left with having to encode accessing the container objects. So for your list example, when enforcing a property on all elements you will need to define auxiliary relations that access the list elements. For example, you can define a recursive relation that is true on Nil, and for non-empty lists holds if the predicate of interest holds on the head of the list and the relation holds recursively on the tail of the list. The catch is of course that such encodings quickly lead to problems where Z3 diverges, predominantly on satisfiable instances. Arrays are of course different: you have direct access to each element in the range of arrays by quantifying over the domain and selecting each index into the array.
2. I don't understand what you mean by 'user assignments'. You can specify time limits by setting options: "(set-option :timeout 1000)" sets a one second timeout.
3. I don't understand your last question. Sorry.